# How can I make window list in GNU Screen appear always ( C-a, C-w)

Tags: gnu-screen

How can I make window list in GNU Screen appear always ( C-a, C-w) ( permanently )

Answer (score 18):

Put the following lines in your `.screenrc`:

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%w"
```

`%w` will show the window list in the status line.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html) for more information about the escape codes.